# Get belongs_to parent object of an unpersisted parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a ProductPrice, Product and Menu

Product belongs_to Menu and ProductPrice to Product.

I'm creating the Product with prices in one time through cocoon nested objects.

In ProductPrice I have this code:

```
def menu
  self.product.menu;
end
```

The price depends on the product_category and the sizes. So when creating a new product, the user selects the category it belongs to and then through ajax the product_prices are fetched so the user can fill in a price for each size of that product.  Prices are fetched with this procedure:

```
def self.get_product_prices(category_id, product_id)
  if category_id != "0"
    MenuCategory.find(category_id).product_sizes.map do |size|
      if product_id == "0"
        ProductPrice.new({:product_size_id => size.id })
      else
        ProductPrice.find_or_initialize_by_product_size_id_and_product_id(size.id, product_id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

On creating this gives me an error since product is returned as nil.  Is there any way to get the menu the non-persisted product belongs to?  I can see it ProductPrice has a filled in product_id attribute and Product is always created with a filled in menu_id.

Comment: How are you attaching the Product to the ProductPrice?  Normally doing this DOES persist the record to the DB automatically.

Comment: Aha.  This is done through ajax. The price depends on the product_category and the sizes.  So when creating a new product, the user selects the category it belongs to and then through ajax the product_prices are fetched so the user can fill in a price for each size of that product.  It's probably there where it's going wrong because it only uses product_id.  I'll update my question with the code that returns the prices and will keep looking with this new info.  Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to pass the product_id in the ajax as a parameter, but I need to find a way to pass the newly created @product itself (or a reference to it). Gotta continue the search tomorrow (3AM here).

Comment: @rept, Did you find a solution?  I having the same question because I'm trying to break some circular dependencies in FactoryGirl.  i.e. `association :menu, strategy: :build` in the product factory, and `association :product, strategy: :build` in the menu factory obviously causes a stack overflow, but I want a way to know that whichever model my test code creates, the other will be created with it.

Comment: @IsaacBetesh just looked it up and added the answer below.  How this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your classes are defined as follows:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu
  has_one :product_price
end

class ProductPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  def menu
    product.menu
  end
end
```

The problem you're describing can only occur if product is indeed not assigned. With that said you may need to write tests to make sure that whatever part of your application that is  accessing `product` as `nil` either does not happen or handled graciously. Also, maybe add a validation to make sure `ProductPrice` has an association to `Product` when each object is created.

```
class ProductPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  validates :product, :presence => true

  def menu
    product.menu
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi amesee,
But the problem isn't that the product_price doesn't have a product, because it has.  And that product also has a menu.  The problem is that product isn't persisted at that time (it will be a bit later in the code) and thus I cannot access self.product.menu.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more insight I can give with the information you've provided. As far as I know, Ruby and Rails is well tested and reliable enough to not return `nil` for no reason. Hence my suggestion to write tests because you're definitely doing something wrong. Sorry if that sounds mean, but just telling me that something is not a problem without providing any details or "proof" of some sort is really unproductive and clearly shows you're not putting in any effort in trying to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the def menu into:

```
def menu
  if !self.product.nil?
    self.product.menu
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not `delegate :menu, to: :product, allow_nil: true`?  Anyway, doesn't really solve my issue, but I found another solution.  I'll post it in an answer here because it's somewhat relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a has_one/belongs_to relationship where each one validates the presence of the other.  In test code in particular, this made it a challenge to stub one of them without either bypassing validation or overflowing the stack.

The solution was:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :person do
    ignore do
      skip_address false
    end
    after(:build) do |person, evaluator|
      person.address ||= FactoryGirl.build(:address, :person => person) unless evaluator.skip_address
    end
  end
  factory :address do
    ignore do
      skip_person false
    end
    after(:build) do |address, evaluator|
      address.person ||= FactoryGirl.build(:person, :address => address) unless evaluator.skip_person
    end
  end
end
```

The ignore allows you to override when you want to test the validation code.

A better design approach would have been to make it all one table, but, unfortunately, it is a legacy DB.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take the following models settings from the answer above just as an example

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end 

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu
  has_one :product_price
end
```

And now, as easy as it is, you just need to add `:inverse_of` to the association on the Menu and Product classes, like this:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, inverse_of: :menu
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu, inverse_of: :product
  has_one :product_price
end
```

and now if you do something like this:

```
menu = Menu.new
product = menu.products.new
product.menu
```

you get your menu object instead of nil